# WinForms ListView.HideSelection property has no effect?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, .net-2.0

I'm working on an application in which a list view is used to select what set of data to display. When the user clicks a list item, the main view updates with the data associated with the selected item, and the ListView control loses focus. Upon losing focus, the control stops highlighting the selected item even though I've explicitly set HideSelection to false.

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):
*"true if the selected item does not appear highlighted when the control loses focus; false if the selected item still appears highlighted when the control loses focus. The default is true."*

Is this a bug, or am I missing something? We are using .NET version 2.0. (Yes, I've checked that the property isn't set anywhere outside of the designer-generated code)

---

Edit: Apparently the selection *was* highlighted, albeit very subtly. After looking through the list of properties I don't see a way to change the highlighting color when the control doesn't have focus. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You need owner drawing to change the colors of selected rows. Or you could use ObjectListView which already knows how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure it isn't just really, really hard to see. On my screen the difference is white vs "really really pale grey" - very subtle. It is more obvious if you change the `ListView`'s background colour while you investigate (also, try turning down your VDU brightness).

Shown below; the "def" is actually selected.

[image: No, really it is]

Comment: Hah, you're right! When I looked at my monitor from a different angle it appeared quite clearly. How silly. I don't suppose you know of a way to change the color of the selection when the control doesn't have focus?

Comment: @Martin - no, I don't; sorry.

Comment: I might have to resort to some form of custom rendering, then. Thanks anyway -- you saved me many a headache trying to figure out why it wasn't showing up! :)

Comment: I'll accept your solution as it answers my original question, and because it seems that there is no way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do without customizing the rendering of the ListView. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just ran into this same issue and making various background color selections I happened to discover if the background color is set to "Control", it changes to the standard "Blue" selection highlight.

Comment: @BLaminack's is what you're looking for. Changing the BackColor to SystemColors.Control works great!

Answer (score 3):

Some LCD monitors do indeed have a problem showing the gray color distinctive enough.  It is a system setting and affects all programs, you cannot change it for just your own.  Given that this really a problem with your monitor, there's little reason to not just fix it by changing the system color.

Use Control Panel + Display.  On Win7 click Personalization, Window Color, Advanced Appearance Settings.  Select "Disabled Item" in the dialog.

Comment: Interestingly, that changed the appearance of essentially *every* inactive control but the list view. I'm stuck with a localized Windows version, so I might have picked the wrong setting.

Comment: This is exactly my problem! Thanks for this post.   I've inherited a project which uses some really weird and cryptic visual updating mechanisms, and I've been wrestling with what appeared to be some sort of override or sidestepping of the HideSelection property (a very real possibility in this code), before thinking to slide the form over to my other monitor.   Sure enough the disabled coloring was there, faintly visible.   Even knowing that's the problem, I still can't get the default disabled color to show on my main monitor no matter what combination of constrast + brightness I use.